# Recall kubernetes annotations in other manifests

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

In my deployment.yaml I know how to pass an env variable to the pod, with value being the value of a field in the yaml - e.g. if I wanted to pass the name of the deployment as POD_NAME:

```
- name: POD_NAME
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      fieldPath: metadata.name
```

What's beyond nice, is to pass also some dynamic data coming from after the deployment has been applied, such as the name of the node or the IP

```
- name: NODE_NAME
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      fieldPath: spec.nodeName 
- name: POD_IP
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      fieldPath: status.podIP
```

However this is good for same-file attributes, i.e. POD_NAME's value comes from a field in the same yaml.

Enter the case of horizontalpodautoscaler, on an external metric:

```
external:
  metricName: loadbalancing.googleapis.com|https|request_count
  metricSelector:
    matchLabels:
      resource.labels.target_proxy_name: k8s-tps-appname-appname-ingress--bc0438048d5e90
```

I have a selector based on a label `resource.labels.target_proxy_name`.

I would like to reference the annotation `target-proxy` of the ingress instead of declaring (hardcoding) `k8s-tps-appname-appname-ingress--bc0438048d5e90`

Is it possible somehow?

Thanks,

Comment: My English is broken today, I was wondering if there's a better word than "recall", for the title. Please advise :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible. For the `matchLabels` field you must provide a string as value. You don't have any means there like the `fieldRef` for container environment variables.

A possible way to solve this problem is to create a custom [MutatingAdmissionWebhook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#mutatingadmissionwebhook) admission controller which listens for the creation of HorizontalPodAutoscalers and inserts the annotation of the corresponding Ingress in the `matchLabels` field before it is persisted in the database.